# How to quickly warm up a toilet seat

Tags: temperature, bathroom, comfort

In the winter, the porcelain toilet seats can get extremely cold and are just unpleasant to sit on in the event that 'doody' calls.

**Is there a quick way to warm up the toilet seat to make it more comfortable to sit on?**

Comment: Just go quickly whenever somebody finishes their thing, it should be still warm. This should work especially in women's toilet.

Comment: @kenorb I've always been of the opinion that one of the few things worse than a cold toilet seat is one that's still warm ;)

Comment: Get really close and breathe on it like when you try to fog up a window.

Comment: Not a hack, but a cheap solution: Buy a wooden seat. Wooden seats don't feel that cold in the beginning and their surface warm up almost immediately when you sit down. The expensive (unhacky) solution is a heated seat, but they start at roughly 250 bucks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume both warming up and insulating the toilet seat from the skin will give the same comfort.

**1. Socks**

Place socks on either side of the toilet seat. This will prevent the direct contact of buttocks with the toilet seat, but there are some risks involved in it as the socks may get germs, so be sure to wash them afterwards.

**2. Toilet paper**

Fold the toilet paper three or four times and place it on one side of the seat, ensuring that it covers one side of the oval seat. Do the same for other side.

**3. Rub with Napkin**

Rub the seat with towel napkin until it warms up to the satisfactory level.

**4. Artificial seat made of cloth**

Stitch a seat shaped material with some thin layer of insulating material. Have some sets of this. Replace it daily.

Answer (score 7):

I sit on it for a few seconds with my pants on. This lets enough heat transfer that it warms up, but not so much that its unbearable.

Answer (score 4):

A porcelain toilet feels cold because porcelain is good at transfering heat. You can buy plastic or wood [toilet seats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_seat): this is a ring that is placed on top of the toilet, and attached to the toilet via a hinge.
Plastic and wood don't transfer heat as easily as porcelain, so they don't feel as cold.

Comment: loved my wood toilet seats, they look good too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a minute to spare before sitting, try using a blow dryer, otherwise known as a hair dryer, on it. That should work pretty well, but only if you aren't dancing from holding it in.

A prevention method, and not really a hack, is to buy either a heated seat or one of those cushioned seats which will still be cold but should warm up much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Soak toilet paper with hot water.
Rub the toilet paper on the ring of the seat and squeeze out the water.
Then dry the toilet seat. 
The toilet seat is now warm.

Answer (score 2):

Just use about 1/4" thick of foam from appliances, cut out a shape to fit your toilet seat. Remove and hang it up after each use.

[image]

Comment: How easily can this be washed? Seems like it could get a little gross after a while.

Answer (score 2):

I took a heating pad we weren't using anymore. One of the long kind and not the short heating pads. I tied it around the toilet lid with the majority of the pad facing the toilet seat. The heating pad has two straps on each end, so I tied them together on the back (top) of the lid.

Now, everyone must  close the lid regardless of user's gender. I plugged it in at the sink outlet (I also swapped out the standard outlet with a GFI). I set the heat control just a tad before the lowest setting. In other words, when it was on the lowest setting (one) it was too warm ( like hot), so I turned the dial more towards the off position, to where it's just  registering 'on'. Perfect!!.

I leave that puppy on 24/7 for the most part because you never know when you have to go. The women love it and I sit regardless of my  purpose for using the toilet. Long gone are the days of having to stand just  to conform to social expectations. An added plus is no more splatters to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Three rather simple methods you could use before/instead of sitting down on the cold seat:

1. *Preheat the toilet seat* by rubbing the ring for a while using your hands
2. *Add some insulation*, like covering the ring with toilet paper
3. *Avoid sitting on the it*, squat over it like they do in some cultures

Answer (score 1):

A very cheap and effective method that I have used while living in the mountains, is to use a tennis ball. Keep the tennis ball next to the toilet, and before you sit down, vigorously run the ball along the seat. Press down hard, because the key to warming it up is to create heat from friction. With practice, you can get the seat nice and toasty in about ten seconds.

Answer (score 1):

My business has no heat so I keep a little heater and I heat gun in the restroom.  I start the heater when I go in and use the heat gun to heat the toilet in about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

We use to wash it with boiled water to keep it warm in winter season.

Answer (score 0):

I always switch the waterline on the back to the hot waterline. if you don't have one by a flexible cord and go in the basement switch it around

Comment: you flush the toilet with hot water? That's the least efficient way to heat up the toilet seat.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution for this is a [electric bidet toilet seat](http://simpletoilet.com/best-bidet-toilet-seat/). It is more hygienic and after you wash your anus you can warm your back just pressing a button!! It's awesome and reduce the using of toilet tissue paper as well as your cost.

Comment: Can the user solve this problem without buying a new seat? It can be a solution itself.